# Sort and display custom post types Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I have an option page, and created the following code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_global_custom_options');
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'Random', 'Order', 'Category' ) );
function add_global_custom_options()
{
    add_options_page('Sort Registrar List', 'Sort Registrar List', 'manage_options', 'functions','global_custom_options');
}

function global_custom_options()
{
    $options = array (
    'random' =>  array(
      'post_type' => 'registrar',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
      ),
    'category' =>  array(
      'post_type' => 'registrar',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'ASC'
      ),
    'menu_order' =>  array(
      'post_type' => 'registrar',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'DESC'
      )
        );

?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Sort Registrar List</h2>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
            <p><strong>Display Randomly:</strong><br />
                <input type="radio" name="random" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('random'); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p><strong>Display by Category:</strong><br />
                <input type="radio" name="category" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('category'); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p><strong>Display By Order:</strong><br />
                <input type="radio" name="order" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('menu_order'); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Store Options" /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="random,category,menu_order" />
        </form>
    </div>
        <?php
}
?>
```

But Im kinda lost in how im getting my page to display the checked value. 
Its supposed to display custom post types either randomly - by order or by catogory depending on what is chosen in the option page in admin panel.

Does anyone have a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup is not 100% correct, you never hit the options.php to process the update, and you forgot to `esc_attr`; this sample is working but it will need more changes to do what you need at 100% but here you can find some clues in how to do it [How can I set and get the values of a multiple select with the Wordpress settings API for a theme options page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987233/how-can-i-set-and-get-the-values-of-a-multiple-select-with-the-wordpress-setting);

```
function add_global_custom_options(){
    add_options_page(
        'Sort Registrar List',
        'Sort Registrar List',
        'manage_options',
        'order_by_options',
        'global_custom_options'
    );

    add_action('admin_init', 'register_new_options');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_global_custom_options');

function register_new_options(){
    register_setting( 'global_custom_option', 'register_new_option_random' );
    register_setting( 'global_custom_option', 'register_new_option_category' );
    register_setting( 'global_custom_option', 'register_new_option_menu_order' );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'register_new_option');

function global_custom_options(){


    //this look unsed.... for debugger it is ;)
    $options = array (
        'random' =>  array(
            'post_type' => 'download',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'rand'
        ),
        'category' =>  array(
            'post_type' => 'download',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'ASC'
        ),
        'menu_order' =>  array(
            'post_type' => 'download',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Sort Registrar List</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'global_custom_option' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'global_custom_option' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Display Randomly</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_new_option_random" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('register_new_option_random') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Display by Category:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_new_option_category" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('register_new_option_category') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Display By Order:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_new_option_menu_order" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('register_new_option_menu_order') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I could not figure out how to use above to get it to work.

Comment: @PatrickZiebellThøgersen Still stuck mate? hmmm what cant you figure out? how to get the values out?

Comment: yes. depending on chosen option I cant get it to display either random . by order or by cat